# No layout found when accessing /sitecore. I am trying to access it for the first time

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

No layout found when accessing **mylocalwebsite.local/sitecore**. I am trying to run it for the first time, restored DBs, granted permission to AppPool etc.

I get a redirect to 404 and the url changes to:

```
/no-layout?item=%2fsitecore&layout=%7b00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%7d&device=Default 
no layout
```

*Please note, I am on Sitecore 6.5*

Comment: I think I found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct `Sitecore, Sitecore modules and sitecore_files` folders. In my case the total size of combined folders was only **11MB**, so I copied the original folders from a new Sitecore 6.5 (12009) instance, which combined was > **140MB**  in size